# Android Theme.Translucent on ICS render all the child elements as gingerbread

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application where I have set the following theme to one of my activities so that I have a nice translucent background.

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

This works pretty well with versions before 14 (ICS), but on ICS, although the activity is shown with translucent background, all the elements inside the activity start using Gingerbread theme. i.e. the buttons inside the activity are displayed with yellow highlight when selected instead of blue on ICS. Similarly, a spinner button when activated/clicked display the items as dialog instead of ICS popup/popdown style.

Can anyone please help me on how to get the translucent background along with the ICS theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the blue highlight from ICS and up you need to use a Holo theme, all other themes will render components as if they are being displayed on Gingerbread and below because that is how the theme is telling the system to render them.

You could extend the Holo theme of your choice and use the members from the translucent theme which will give you your desired effect on ICS and above.

The theme data is available in `<android-sdk>/platforms/android-<API-level>/data/res/`